# How to create a jagged array x by x from 3 arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, jagged-arrays

I have 3 int arrays

```
 var x= new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 }; 
 var y= new int[] { 2, 2, 3, 2, 4 };
 var z= new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 3 };
```

And I would like to create a 5 rows 3 columns jagged array, like this:

[image: Array I need]

can anyone help me please thanks.

Comment: Your array contains the 5 elements so I think you need [3][5] array.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
var x = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 };
var y = new int[] { 2, 2, 3, 2, 4 };
var z = new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 3 };
int[][] jagged = new int[][] { x, y, z };
```

Comment: dummy,  I ask wrong. what I really want is a 5 by 3, but anyway thanks for answer my question

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it as below:

```
var x= new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 }; 
var y= new int[] { 2, 2, 3, 2, 4 };
var z= new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 3 };      

int[][] jagged = new[] { x, y, z };
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers show you how to easily get the 3 by 5 array (`new[] { x, y, z }`). To get the 5 by 3 array as you want, you "simply" *transpose* the 3 by 5.

Something like:

```
public static T[][] Transpose<T>(T[][] arrays)
{
    // sanity checks omitted
    var columns = arrays.Length;
    var rows = arrays.Select(x => x.Length).Max();

    var matrix = new T[rows][];

    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        matrix[row] = new T[columns];

        for (var column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            // proper bounds checks omitted
            matrix[row][column] = arrays[column][row];
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop will do:

```
var x= new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 }; 
var y= new int[] { 2, 2, 3, 2, 4 };
var z= new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 3 };  

int [][] jagged =new int[5][];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    jagged[i] = new int[]{x[i],y[i],z[i]};
```